# Debugging a MySQL charset error

Tags: java, mysql, jpa, character-encoding

I have a project where I scrape some data from a HTML file, put it into a MySQL database and then read it out again and display it to the user. Whenever the servlet is inserting something into the DB the "£" sign is being inserted as a � and when read out again presented as that.

The application is written in Java (with Spring) and JPA with EclipseLink as the JPA implementation.

I have narrowed down the problem to the insertion into MySQL since when I view the table in the console the question mark appears.

I have configured MySQL to use UTF-8 as the standard encoding in my.cnf

```
[mysqld]
default-character-set=utf8
```

If I run

```
SHOW TABLE STATUS;
```

I can see that the collation on the tables is

```
utf8_general_ci
```

which suggests that the char set is also UTF-8.

Also there is this:
mysql> SHOW CREATE DATABASE gate;

```
+----------+---------------------------------------------------------------+
| Database | Create Database                                               |
+----------+---------------------------------------------------------------+
| gate     | CREATE DATABASE `gate` /*!40100 DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 */ | 
+----------+---------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

So, with Java being fully unicode(?) and my DB being set to UTF-8 where could I look for misconfigurations/errors?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

in your HTML page?

Answer (score 0):

What is your connection character set? Take a look at [Connect/J configuration properties](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/connector-j-reference-configuration-properties.html) as well as a section on [dealing with charsets](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/connector-j-reference-charsets.html)

Answer (score 0):

You should also tell your mysql driver to use utf8

```
db.url=jdbc:mysql://HOST:3306/DB?characterEncoding=utf8
```